# AxWebBrowser in VB.net how to work with java script?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

i have a vb.net GUIform that will display an AxWebBrowser to show a html table which have some interactive controls that required javascript to work.

I already prepared the javascript with the valid functions.

Example:
Inside AxWebBrowser have a button, when i pressed the button, it will display the current time inside the AxWebBrowswer.

Is that possible to do this? and how? Just place the .js file in the same place and set the src equals to the .js file path? but it seems not work.
And after several tried, i found maybe JScriptCodeProvider can do this. but i no idea how to point the src to the jscript running in memory.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to include the javascript with the html via a `<script>` tag, paste the entire script inline rather than using `src="..."` if you need to.

Comment: u mean doing by using internal scripting right? I have tried this also, but when i press the button on AxWebBrowser , system prompt me

"the value of the property "displayDate" is null or undefined, not a function object"